# I have to write a code that uses classes for DNA, RNA, and Protein. Im stuck on the first part

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, methods

I have to take a users input int as length of the dna a sequence. Im trying to return the numberString but i get an issue with my array every time

Driver

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GenBank1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a desired DNA sequence length, between 1 and 10 please:");
        int inputLength = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(inputLength);
        System.out.println(DNA1.toNumString(inputLength));

        int[] baseId = new int[inputLength];
        for(int i=0;i<=baseId.length;i++){
            baseId[i]=inputLength;
            int rndmr = (int)(4.0*Math.random());
            baseId[i]-=rndmr;
                System.out.print(baseId[i]+1 + ",");
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please describe your issue better. What is the exact issue that is happening? what do you want to happen?

Comment: You have to be more descriptive.  As in, what sort of issue are you having?

Comment: Check out http://sscce.org for hints on how to ask a good question, then edit the question.

Comment: Is it, by chance, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i=0;i<=baseId.length;i++)
```

You should probably do

```
for(int i=0;i<baseId.length;i++)
```

since, in an array with (say) 10 entries, they will have indices 0 to 9. Trying to look up array[10] will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the DNA1 class is and what the function of the program is, I would not be able to comment futher. However yes, you will experience     ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to correct this the following should work

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GenBank1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a desired DNA sequence length, between 1 and 10 please:");
    int inputLength = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(inputLength);
    System.out.println(DNA1.toNumString(inputLength));

    int[] baseId = new int[inputLength];
    for(int i=0;i<baseId.length;i++){  
        baseId[i]=inputLength;
        int rndmr = (int)(4.0*Math.random());
        baseId[i]-=rndmr;
            System.out.print(baseId[i]+1 + ",");
    }    
}    
}
```

Your ending clause for your FOR loop wanted to go from 0 -> length which would be wrong as you will go over the Array index.